# Cannot run rsync when pushing to linux server

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, ssh, rsync

When I try to sync a directory with the following command

```
rsync -r ssh /path/to/file user@IP:/destination
```

I get the following error code

```
rsync: Failed to exec ssh: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(84) [sender=3.0.7]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(603) [sender=3.0.7]
```

First off I know there are tons of links out there with this exact same problem but none of them have been helpful for me. Quite a lot of them recommend installing openssh which I already have and works fine on its own. I don't use cygwin either, so many other posts weren't helpful. Also, I've tried many variants of the above command line.

Some details of my implementation are that my local laptop uses Windows 10, the server I am trying to push to uses Ubuntu 18.04. I can easily create an ssh link between the two and rsync works perfectly fine on both devices when they are just copying files locally.

I don't know where my rsync package comes from because it was already installed on my computer when I got it, but the executable is located here: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Empirum\rsync.exe`

and ssh is located here `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`

the openssh folder is in my path so I don't know why rsync would have trouble finding it. I've been banging my head on this problem for a while now so any help would be very appreciated

Comment: In a cmd window, does `dir /path/to/file` work as expected?  How about `dir "/path/to/file"`?

Comment: It does work when I put the slashes the right way, which I forget all the time

Comment: Looks like `ssh` is not in your PATH? But the `ssh` in your command is strange anyway. Either you need `-e "ssh ...options...*`, or you don't need it at all since it's the default when using a single colon in the destination: `user@IP::/destination` doesn't use ssh, but `user@IP:/destination` does.

Comment: I've tried tons of combinations with and without ssh and none of them worked. I haven't explored -e options but I already found a workaround in using src to just copy all the files every time. Not very elegant but my files aren't too big so it's fine